# How to detect input number warnings and ignore them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I need a way to bypass these warnings so the value can be checked manually later. Is this possible?

**edit1**: I did not think my reasons were necessary. I chose the `number` type because it restricts the input of letters even if it's by copy-pasting, while allowing all possible keyboard commands, which would have been complex to do by picking a `text` type and putting restrictions on `keydown` and `paste` to let the user know that this field isn't for words before calling an ajax and checking the other stuff.

Here is the HTML code of the `input` (it's not the same as the image above):

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" name="price" />
```

The attributes are for restricting if the user uses the up and down arrows.

Comment: Why do you have HTML5 validation if you don't want it?

Comment: It seems some kind of HTML5 validation on the numeric input, you will need to remove the relevant attributes from the `<input />`. Post the HTML code.

Comment: @Juhana reasons added.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia HTML code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `novalidate` attribute to the form.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp